# What are toasts? Can I eat those?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the social tab under the options menu, there's a checkbox that reads `Show Toast Windows`, and then a duration for these toasts, what are they? how can I use them, and what are they for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [Toast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toast_(computing)) is what shows up whenever you earn an achievement. It flashes the achievement name across the bottom of the screen.

If you find them distracting, you can disable them with a menu option.

Comment: They are called **toast windows** as they traditionally popup from the bottom of the screen just like a toast would popup from the toaster when ready.